# Pythagorean metaphysics

Tags: metaphysics, pythagoras

I have developed an interest in studying Pythagoras, mainly his idea of Number as the Arche. It seems that neither him nor his school left any writings, and what survives of it comes through Aristotle's and Plato's references in their respective pieces. However, according to [Aristotle's Sources for Pythagorean Doctrine (J. A. Philip, 1963)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1086378?read-now=1&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), Aristotle only ever makes two references to Pythagoras himself. So, where could one read about the Pythagorean school of thought and its cosmogony, in a way that's the farthest possible from second-hand?

Comment: See [Pythagoras](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pythagoras/) and [Pythagoreanism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pythagoreanism/) and follow the links to Archytas and Philolaus.

Comment: See also the posts : [Pythagoras vs. the idea of Pythagoras](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/391/pythagoras-vs-the-idea-of-pythagoras) and [Existence of Pythagoras Resources](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7682/existence-of-pythagoras-resources).

Comment: I am afraid, you are out of luck. According to modern scholars, most of what came down to us about Pythagoras, including through Plato and Aristotle, is a fabrication. The classical work is [Burkert, Lore and Science in Ancient Pythagoreanism](https://books.google.com/books/about/Lore_and_Science_in_Ancient_Pythagoreani.html?id=0qqp4Vk1zG0C), see also [Zhmud Pythagoras and the Early Pythagoreans](https://books.google.com/books/about/Pythagoras_and_the_Early_Pythagoreans.html?id=of-ghBD9q1QC). "All is number" that piqued your interest is neo-Pythagorean gloss on Aristotle's "creative" narrative

Comment: @william since most  of pythagoras' is lost, and most of what we know about it is fabricated, I do not recommend spending much time on that, because set aside pythagoras mathematics and metaphysics of ratios, what is left is a collection of cults that look more like religion than philosophy. I personally think that the real deal in the pre-socratic era begins with Parmenides and Zeno of Elea. On the other hand it's very likely that pythagorean subject matters are revisited later in history, albeit under different names.

Comment: @SmootQ I've read about Aristotle's pythagoreanism and your comment's bit about "religion" clicked. Indeed, in "A review of Aristotle’s claim regarding Pythagoreans fundamental Beliefs: All is number?", it's clear that the mystical sense in number is strong for Aristotle, making it *rather a materialization of number than
a mathematization of nature*, being the latter what I was searching. But could you point to something related to the "metaphysics of ratios"?

Comment: @William Oops ! My mistake , it is called cosmology not metaphysics in this case. And ratios are what is also called 'Numbers', some say 'Numbers' and some 'Ratios'. There is also this idea of reincarnation (metempsychosis) https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pythagoras/   I am afraid I do not know of any resources that I can confidently point to and say : This is the right one.

Comment: According to https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/philolaus/#EpiRolNum I believe the "All is Number" was an existing Pythagorean view in the epistemological sense, but Aristotle interpreted the Pythagorean writings under his own philosophy, ending up with an ontological view of the "All is Number" — as in numbers are things that compound other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kenneth Sylvan Guthrie's *[Complete Pythagoras](https://archive.org/details/TheCompletePythagoras)* may be one place to start.

Patrick Roussel describes the collection as

> *The Complete Pythagoras* is a compilation of two books. The first is entitled *The Life of Pythagoras* that contains the four biographies that have survived from antiquity....The second is entitled *Pythagorean Library* and is a complete collection of the surviving fragments from the Pythagoreans.

---

Guthrie, K. S. Complete Pythagoras. Retrieved on June 16, 2019 from *Internet Archive* at https://archive.org/details/TheCompletePythagoras

Comment: Maybe is worth noting (to avoid too many wrong "expectations") that Pythagoras lived in 6th Century BCE while the author of *The Life of Pythagoras* was [Iamblichus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iamblichus) who lived AD 245 – ca.325, which means around 1.000 years later.

Comment: I think that's pretty much the best I could possibly get, together with Allegranza's commentaries. I'll wait +24h so I can greencheck this asnwer.